# Is it possible to cast Youtube video to Styled Media Receiver app? [Chromecast]

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast

I have `Styled Media Receiver` app on the web side, and I need to cast `Youtube` video from my `Android` sender app, by providing a link to it. If I cast a mp4 file, it works, but with youtube link - no.
I saw there was an ability to do casting with the previous SDK.. is there any chance to cast youtube video with the newest SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, with the current official SDK, you cannot do that.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your response. Do you know if somebody tried to do that by writing custom receivers with embedding Youtube player via iFrames? or maybe some other workarounds..

Comment: Some folks have tried doing the embedded YT but as far as I recall, it only works for a subset of videos, not all.